# looping and display model's associated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am looping through a set of records and would like to display the model's associated data at the same time.
However when trying to display the associated data, am getting an error message

Can anyone tell me What's wrong with the following code?

```
<% @subs.each do |submission| %>
    <%= submission.SUB_OID %>
    <%= submission.SUB_ASSAY_TYPE %>
    <%= submission.author.AUT_NAME %> -- am getting the error because of this line

<% end %>
```

Model:
Sub has_one Author
Author belongs_to Sub

If i remove this line `<%= submission.author.AUT_NAME %>`, the list of submissions are displayed properly, however when i include the 3rd line, i get the error 'Undefines method for AUT_NAME'.

I don't understand where the error is found.

Am a newbie and would be grateful for any suggestion provided

Comment: Does the Author model have an `AUT_NAME` attribute or method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I included the following if condition --

<% if submission.author %>
<%= submission.author.AUT_NAME %>
<% end %>

The reason why author name couldn't be displayed was because not all submissions have an associated entry in the authors table.

Comment: In recent Rails you may use the method 'try': `submission.author.try(:AUT_NAME)` which, instead of raising an exception, will return 'nil' if the author is nil. The code may be more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Arsen, the try method really seems to be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Either your `author` has no field/method named `AUT_NAME` or your relationship is wrong. Can you check if `submission.author` is nil and make sure `AUT_NAME` exists?